# Only perform javascript operation if page contains specific class

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write some code that either operates only if a class exists on that page or using an else if, slightly changes the css of that JS code on any other page. The code I have written is obviously wrong but I believe kind of highlights what I am trying to do.
In essence, if the body tag contains a class of `single`-st_tours, I want to look for an element containing a class of `lh1em` and perform a JavaScript operation. If it does not contain that class, I want to perform the same operation but change the inline css slightly. As my code is now, I am getting the wrong display. Here is my code:

```js
let doubleMessage = document.getElementsByClassName('lh1em');
let ifClassExists = document.getElementsByClassName('single-st_tours');
if (ifClassExists === 'single-st_tours') {
  Array.from(doubleMessage).forEach(function(itemMessage) {
    itemMessage.insertAdjacentHTML(
      'afterend',
      '<br><span style="font-size: 12px; color:#fff;">Price Based On double Occupancy</span>'
    );
  });
} else {
  Array.from(doubleMessage).forEach(function(itemMessage) {
    itemMessage.insertAdjacentHTML(
      'afterend',
      '<br><span style="font-size: 12px; color:#000;">Price Based On double Occupancy</span>'
    );
  });
}
```

```html
<body class="single-st_tours">
  <div class="form-head">
    <div class="price">
      <span class="label">from </span>
      <span class="value">
        <span class="text-lg lh1em item"> $3,650.00</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

All my code is in one as I am just testing right now.
If anyone can help me get closer, I would sure appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you check the output of [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and compare it to a string. Its actually an element list also called HTML Collection, which may or may not be empty.

Check instead if the list has at least 1 element.

```js
let doubleMessage = document.getElementsByClassName('lh1em');
let ifClassExists = document.getElementsByClassName('single-st_tours');

// here is your fix
if (ifClassExists.length > 0 ) {
...
```

Comment: Thank you @The Fool. The body of each page contains a huge number of classes but the one I want to target also contains the class single-st_tours. So wouldn't my .length >0 always be true no matter what. And in that case, how can I evaluate if just that one class so happens to exist? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Dont you only pull the elements into this list which have that class in the first place?

Comment: ahhh yes you are right. I was confused because I implemented your solution but am still getting the wrong result.

Comment: No problem. It is working. Duh, I used white text so assumed it wasn't working but when I highlighted it, I could see my text was there and when I removed the class from the body, the text turned black as expected. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok cool, that said, if you really just want to know if 1 exists, maybe use `getElementByClassName` (singular) or `querySelector` instead. This will be a bit more performant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no such thing as getElementByClassName.